# LINQ - group by issues

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I'm trying to transform such a SQL query

```
select qb.Fabricator_id, cj.Client_id,
    (select Name from CustomerBase where Id = qb.Fabricator_id),
    (select ContactEmail from CustomerBase where Id = qb.Fabricator_id)
from ClientJob cj, Quote q, QuoteBid qb
where cj.Client_id in (39343, 39157)
and q.ClientJob_id = cj.Id
and qb.Quote_id = q.Id
group by qb.Fabricator_id, cj.Client_id
order by cj.Client_id, qb.Fabricator_id
```

into LINQ, so far I have such a query

```
var customerId = new[] {39343, 39157};

var query = from cj in _dataContext.ClientJob join q in _dataContext.Quote on cj.Id equals q.ClientJob_id
             join qb in _dataContext.QuoteBid on q.Id equals qb.Quote_id
            where customerId.Contains(cj.Client_id.Value)
            && qb.Fabricator_id.HasValue
            group new { CustomerId = cj.Client_id, FabricatorId = qb.Fabricator_id } by new { qb.Fabricator_id, cj.Client_id} into uniqueFabricators
            from uf in uniqueFabricators
            orderby uf.CustomerId, uf.FabricatorId
            select new
            {
                uf.CustomerId,
                uf.FabricatorId,
                FabricatorName = _dataContext.CustomerBase.Single(_ => _.Id == uf.FabricatorId).Name,
                FabricatorEmail = _dataContext.CustomerBase.Single(_ => _.Id == uf.FabricatorId).ContactEmail
            };
```

which looks quite similar to the SQL one, however, the results are completely different.

If I execute it in LINQPad, the result SQL query looks somewhat similar, but not quite.

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 39343
DECLARE @p1 Int = 39157
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t4].[Client_id] AS [CustomerId], [t6].[Fabricator_id] AS [FabricatorId], (
    SELECT [t7].[Name]
    FROM [CustomerBase] AS [t7]
    WHERE ([t7].[Id]) = [t6].[Fabricator_id]
    ) AS [FabricatorName], (
    SELECT [t8].[ContactEmail]
    FROM [CustomerBase] AS [t8]
    WHERE ([t8].[Id]) = [t6].[Fabricator_id]
    ) AS [FabricatorEmail]
FROM (
    SELECT [t2].[Fabricator_id], [t0].[Client_id]
    FROM [ClientJob] AS [t0]
    INNER JOIN [Quote] AS [t1] ON ([t0].[Id]) = [t1].[ClientJob_id]
    INNER JOIN [QuoteBid] AS [t2] ON ([t1].[Id]) = [t2].[Quote_id]
    WHERE (([t0].[Client_id]) IN (@p0, @p1)) AND ([t2].[Fabricator_id] IS NOT NULL)
    GROUP BY [t2].[Fabricator_id], [t0].[Client_id]
    ) AS [t3]
CROSS JOIN ([ClientJob] AS [t4]
    INNER JOIN [Quote] AS [t5] ON ([t4].[Id]) = [t5].[ClientJob_id]
    INNER JOIN [QuoteBid] AS [t6] ON ([t5].[Id]) = [t6].[Quote_id])
WHERE ((([t3].[Fabricator_id] IS NULL) AND ([t6].[Fabricator_id] IS NULL)) OR (([t3].[Fabricator_id] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t6].[Fabricator_id] IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t3].[Fabricator_id] IS NULL) AND ([t6].[Fabricator_id] IS NULL)) OR (([t3].[Fabricator_id] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t6].[Fabricator_id] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t3].[Fabricator_id] = [t6].[Fabricator_id]))))) AND ((([t3].[Client_id] IS NULL) AND ([t4].[Client_id] IS NULL)) OR (([t3].[Client_id] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t4].[Client_id] IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t3].[Client_id] IS NULL) AND ([t4].[Client_id] IS NULL)) OR (([t3].[Client_id] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t4].[Client_id] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t3].[Client_id] = [t4].[Client_id]))))) AND (([t4].[Client_id]) IN (@p0, @p1)) AND ([t6].[Fabricator_id] IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY [t4].[Client_id], [t6].[Fabricator_id]
```

What is wrong in my LINQ query, can't see the issue.

Thx

Comment: Your SQL doesn't have `qb.Fabricator_id IS NOT NULL`, but your Linq has `qb.Fabricator_id.HasValue`.  Also why didn't you just group by `qb.Name` and `qb.ContactEmail` instead of doing two subqueries, or just use `Distinct` instead of grouping?

Comment: IS  NOT NULL doesn't affect anyhow. I'm grouping by 2 integers, to get the IDs, the subqueries then is just to get more info about these IDs.

Comment: but you don't need them.  You could join to the `CustomerBase` table instead.  Also are you saying the results of running the query are different, or just that the generated SQL is different?  If it's the results, then exactly how are they different.

Comment: The results are different. Well, I solved the problem. This is not needed "from uf in uniqueFabricators
            orderby uf.CustomerId, uf.FabricatorId", now seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The rights query would be

```
    var query = from cj in _dataContext.ClientJob
     join q in _dataContext.Quote on cj.Id equals q.ClientJob_id
     join qb in _dataContext.QuoteBid on q.Id equals qb.Quote_id
     where customerId.Contains(cj.Client_id.Value)
     && qb.Fabricator_id.HasValue
     group new { cj.Client_id, qb.Fabricator_id } by new { qb.Fabricator_id, cj.Client_id } into uniqueFabricators
     orderby uniqueFabricators.Key.Client_id, uniqueFabricators.Key.Fabricator_id
        select new
        {
            uniqueFabricators.Key.Client_id,
            uniqueFabricators.Key.Fabricator_id,
            FabricatorName = _dataContext.CustomerBase.Single(_ => _.Id == uniqueFabricators.Key.Fabricator_id).Name,
            FabricatorEmail = _dataContext.CustomerBase.Single(_ => _.Id == uniqueFabricators.Key.Fabricator_id).ContactEmail
        };
```

no need to use another subquery `from uniqueFabricators`

Comment: It would have been enough to just replace `from uf in uniqueFabricators` with `let uf = uniqueFabricators.Key` in your original query.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use JOIN, in the original SQL request it was not be.

```
var customerId = new[] {39343, 39157};

var query = from subquery in
            (
               from qb in _dataContext.QuoteBid 
               from cj in _dataContext.ClientJob
               from q in _dataContext.Quote
               where customerId.Contains(cj.Client_id) &&
                     q.ClientJob_id = cj.Id &&
                     qb.Quote_id = q.Id
               select new
               {
                  Fabricator_id = qb.Fabricator_id,
                  Client_id = cj.Client_id,
                  Name = CustomerBase.Name,
                  ContactEmail = CustomerBase.ContactEmail 
               }
            )
            group subquery by Fabricator_id into group1
            group group1 by Client_id into group2
            orderby group2.Client_id, group2.Fabricator_id
            select group2;
```